# How does one rebuild a single PHP extension package on Debian?

Tags: php, debian, packages, linux

In trying to get ODBC PDO working with Microsoft's MSSQL driver on Debian I've found that I need to apply patches to the PHP extension (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50444 for those patches).

Having patched the code I want to rebuild the php5-odbc package. I don't really want to have to rebuild all the PHP packages though. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: See this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/ and rebuild php5-odbc.

Comment: @Mark I already know how to fetch the packages' source, patch it, and rebuild the whole set of packages; I'd like to know how to specify that I only want to compile a single package from the set.

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question when wondering this myself.  Simply to browse to the extension directory source then:

1. `phpize` (for versioning extension correctly)
2. `./configure` (with any options needed)
3. `make`

It will probably build in the `libs` folder.  You then just need to copy (and overwrite) the module to your main PHP install i.e. `/usr/lib64/php/modules/{extension}.so`.

Mark